# Downloading a .csv file from a response URL (which contains s3 bucket credentials) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a .csv file from a url as shown below:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/path/to/file/filename?AWSAccessKeyId=Key&Expires=15&Signature=SomeCharacters

The URL is a response which I get from a webservice using python and I can't hard-code the aws credentials since the Signature changes every call and the url remains active for only 15 seconds. I tried the below:

s3.meta.client.download_file('bucketname', url, 'localpath')

and also

`r = requests.get(url, auth=('username','password'), verify=False, stream=True)` 
       `r.raw.decode_content = True`
           `with open("filename", 'wb') as f:`
              `shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)`

But the above methods are not working when it comes to invoking the URL directly. Can someone please suggest something?

Thanks,
Milind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to S3 in python and download a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806612/how-to-connect-to-s3-in-python-and-download-a-csv)

Comment: Does the signed URL download said file when you browse to it in your browser?

Comment: It doesn't download the file if I pasted the signed url in my browser. I suppose this is because it is kept inside a private s3 bucket and I do not own that bucket